# automatically restart an application after a core dump

Tags: linux, high-availability, coredump

I have a linux process but I am taking some core dumps some times.

Simple question: Is there any way/method/program/whatever that is capable of restarting a
process that got killed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/).

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the execution of the process in a shell script that would simply keep restarting the app as it exits.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Soo mentioned, ensure you have a reliable notification mechanism so that you know you're getting frequent restarts.

Consider having a restart counter and stop restarting if you restart either too frequently or too many times.  If you're just crashing, restarting and instantly crashing again that's usually a pretty bad thing.